# MCU firmware configuration

Tags: android, rom

Right now I got my car MCU firmware files. And I do not know if it is possible to edit it and save it.

I want to fix some bugs and add new features or also update android, because it is on Android 4.2.2 API 17.

For more details it is flashing like:

- all files put tu USB flash
- then in car MCU connect from USB cabel

  - and system detects it
  - and tries to install
- in install proccess all steps are in `scatter.mmcboot.ext4.xml` file

  - it goes step by step

My questions are:

- It is some IDE for editing and building this files?
- How can I access Android files from ext4 I think and save it? I want edit or add some applications and flash it on my MCU with new stuff.
- Maybe some one knows what all files do or can tell where I can read about this?
- Can I test it in the emulator?

Thanks.

Comment: Hi and welcome! Looks like you have lot of work and questions. You will get best answers on *superuser* if you ask one very specific question at a time. To get you started, the *xml* file is probably just a text file and can be edited with any text editor. If you want you can get fancy with some [XML editor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_XML_editors).

Comment: Ok. I know how edit XML, but I do not know how to start edit .ext4 data to change android core and so on.. ;/

Comment: I just looked it up and here is the fourth search result [How To Unpack & Repack ext4 Android System Images](https://dorylabs.com/how-to-unpack-repack-ext4-android-system-images/). Looks like you can just mount the image in read/write as you wish. But that does not mean it will magically work when you reflash it back to your device.

Comment: Yeah, but first I want to know how everything fit together before changing something :)

Comment: I would do some extensive research if anyone ever did it before you. Otherwise you will have to figure out everything on your own, and it does not look like streamlined process to me. Good luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to fix some bugs and add new features

To fix bugs or add features you'll most likely require the source code for the problem application. The files you have are the binary images that the system uses to run, not the sources. Without extensive reverse engineering, you won't be able to "*fix*" anything.

> also update android, because it is on Android 4.2.2 API 17

Updating Android is not a small task. It requires a lot of experience and knowledge, and takes hours to build on a powerful workstation.

Even if you were to build a more recent version of Android, you will almost certainly be missing a handful of drivers and other important system details that might well render the head unit unusable - *especially* if their standard update procedure replaces the bootloader ([U-Boot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Das_U-Boot)).

Additionally, if the head unit is designed with any security in mind, installing your own unsigned image could render it unusable.

These problems aren't things you could address - it's very unlikely the manufacturer would be willing to release schematics and sources.

---

In summary, unless you are working on an Open Source head unit with a good community (you didn't mention anything about what it is), this task will be impossible. If there was a good community, then I suspect there would be a more recent release of Android available for it.

Comment: So what is Android Kitchen: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33684741/how-to-unpack-android-lollipop-system-img-ext4-and-add-new-language